# Appium for iOS Test Automation

Tags: ios, selenium, appium

I am using Appium v1.2.2 and after proper configuration for Apple device, I receiving an error on click of Inspector as

Could Not start a new session
Be sure the Appium server is running with an application opened by using the "App Path" parameter in Appium.app (along with package and activity for Android) or by connecting with selenium client and supplying this in the desired capabilities object.

Appreciate heaps if someone can help to resolve this error. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you set App Path correctly? Click on Apple icon on appium UI. You will see app path parameter. Click on checkobox in front of it. and give path to .app or .ipa file of your application